# Filtering a List by a Text Field

Tags: javascript, html, filter

I have a created a small app that helps me be more productive at work. It filters a list of  tags by their text contents. It currently works great for finding contiguous lines of text, but I would prefer to re-implement it as a filter that works for non-contiguous combinations of text.

For example, if the string inside the  tag is "Appleville, MN", the current filter will find it if you type in "Apple" or "Appleville" or "App", but I want to be able to filter successfully with input such as "App MN".

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I'm not sure what exact algorithm I need to go with. Thanks!

**P.S.:** I've included some code below with examples of the kind of search items I am filtering, the current filter function, as well as the search field.

```js
function filterList() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("itemList");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="filterList()" placeholder="Search list..">
<ul id="itemList">
  <li onclick=applevilleMN()><a href="#">Appleville, MN</a></li>
  <li onclick=orangevilleOR()><a href="#">Orangeville, OR</a></li>
  <li onclick=kiwivilleCA()><a href="#">Kiwiville, CA</a></li>
  <li onclick=bananavilleCA()><a href="#">Bananaville, CA</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's a modified version doing what you want.

It splits the filter string by spaces to create an array of filters, `li`s arer shown only if they are valid for each substring of the array.

```js
function filterList() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("itemList");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
      
      // split filter by spaces, gives ["app", "MN"] in your example  
      let filters = filter.split(" ") 

      // remove the empty filters (if your filter string 
      // starts or ends by a space) since they are source of errors

      // Array.filter takes in parameter a function returning a boolean
      // it create a new array containing only element where 
      // the function returned truthy value

      // here we return the length of the string which is falsy (== 0) for "" 
      // and truthy for every other string (!= 0)
      filters = filters.filter(f => f.length)   

      let shouldDisplay = true
      // test each filter and store true only if string contains all filter
      filters.forEach(filt => {
        shouldDisplay = shouldDisplay && txtValue.toUpperCase().includes(filt)
      })
      
      // update visibility
      // set visible if the string include all filters
      // or if there is no filter
      li[i].style.display = (shouldDisplay || filters.length === 0) ? "" : "none";
    }
  }
```

```html
<ul id="itemList">
      <li onclick=applevilleMN()><a href="#" >Appleville, MN</a></li>
      <li onclick=orangevilleOR()><a href="#" >Orangeville, OR</a></li>
      <li onclick=kiwivilleCA()><a href="#" >Kiwiville, CA</a></li>
      <li onclick=bananavilleCA()><a href="#" >Bananaville, CA</a></li>
</ul>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="filterList()" placeholder="Search list.." >
```

docs : [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`truthy values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), [`falsy values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Comment: This also works very well, and is the version I've decided to implement. Could you go into more detail on the following line? I'm not very familiar with js methods yet. "filters = filters.filter(f => f.length) "

Comment: Ah, I see. That's very clear now, thank you so much. :D

Comment: Darn, after further testing it appears that I missed something initially. It's only filtering the list based on the most recent word. For example, it would show both CA entries if you type "kiwi CA" or "bana CA". Do you know why this may be happening?

Comment: @artifc3 ho I didn't see this, I know where it come from, updating the answer to correct this bug ;)

Comment: Thanks for looking into that! I was attempting to fix it myself but couldn't quite get it working. Would you mind going through the logic of the bug fix?

Comment: the problem was I changed the state of the `<li>` on each filter word so only the last word was actually taken into account, with the fix I "sum" every filter and only then apply it to the `li`s

Answer (score 3):

```js
var itensList = document.querySelectorAll('#itemList li');

function filterList() {

var valueInput = document.querySelector('#myInput').value.toLowerCase().trim();

for(var i = 0; i < itensList.length; i++){
  var item = itensList[i];
  var valueLi = item.innerText.toLowerCase().trim();

  item.style.display = valueLi.search(new RegExp(valueInput.replace(/\s+/, '|'))) != -1 ? '' : 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="filterList()" placeholder="Search list..">
<ul id="itemList">
  <li onclick=applevilleMN()><a href="#">Appleville, MN</a></li>
  <li onclick=orangevilleOR()><a href="#">Orangeville, OR</a></li>
  <li onclick=kiwivilleCA()><a href="#">Kiwiville, CA</a></li>
  <li onclick=bananavilleCA()><a href="#">Bananaville, CA</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, this works beautifully! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [fuse.js](https://fusejs.io/). Its an approximate string matching libraray, and its is lightweight and easy to set up. You only need to feed it with list of objects and use the object's key as its key.

```js
const cities = [{
    state: "MN",
    city: "Appleville"
  },
  {
    state: "OR",
    city: "Orangeville"
  },
  {
    state: "CA",
    city: "Kiwiville"
  },
  {
    state: "CA",
    city: "Bananaville"
  }
]
var options = {
  shouldSort: true,
  threshold: 0.6,
  location: 0,
  distance: 100,
  maxPatternLength: 32,
  minMatchCharLength: 2,
  keys: ['state', 'city']
}
var fuse = new Fuse(cities, options)

const input = document.getElementById("myInput")

input.oninput = (event) => {
  const results = fuse.search(event.target.value)
  for (result of results) {
    console.log(result.state, result.city)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fuse.js/3.4.5/fuse.min.js"></script>

<ul id="itemList">
  <li onclick=applevilleMN()><a href="#">Appleville, MN</a></li>
  <li onclick=orangevilleOR()><a href="#">Orangeville, OR</a></li>
  <li onclick=kiwivilleCA()><a href="#">Kiwiville, CA</a></li>
  <li onclick=bananavilleCA()><a href="#">Bananaville, CA</a></li>
</ul>

<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search list..">
```

> #### Threshold
>
> At what point does the match algorithm give up. A threshold of 0.0 requires a perfect match (of both letters and location), a threshold
>   of 1.0 would match anything. - fuse.js

Thrashold is the most important factor when its comes to word matching. As of now, it matchs words that are 40% similar to the input. If you think its quite wide, decrease the number.